# Compressing a string of bits (e.g. "000100111110001")

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need a JavaScript procedure that compresses a string of bits this way:

```
/*
Compress bitsring by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
characters followed by the character. 
EXAMPLES:
"10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
"001100011111111111111" --> "0011309151"
*/
```

Preferably, the procedure would be elegant. I've tried creating one and it's getting messy:

```
curIdx = 0;
while (curIdx < bitsring.length)
{
    cnt = 1;
    while ((curIdx + cnt < bitString.length) && (cnt < 10) && (bitsring.charAt(curIdx) == bitsring.charAt(curIdx + cnt))
       ......   

    }
}
```

Yeah, I know I'm probably going about this the wrong way because I have nested while loops and triple `&&` conditions and stuff like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `parseInt('000100111110001',2).toString(16)` gives `9f1`. You can prepend the number of preceding 0's separated with `_` if you want to restore those.

Comment: What class is this for?

Comment: What happens when there are 11 consecutive bits?  Or 10 or 101 or 111...you get the idea.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "elegant"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey By "elegant" I mean like a 1-liner or something that doesn't look messy

Comment: @EthanBrown: The user gives an example for that case. If there are 14 `1`s in a row, you would print `9151`. While this isn't a great compression routine, it is reversible.

Comment: You could do like @Matt's solution, but use base 36 for greater compression if the values will be larger..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp with a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)?

```
function compress(input) {
    return input.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return ($0.length + $1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regular expression `String.replace` with a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
string.replace(/(0{3,9}|1{3,9})/g, function (match) {
    return "" + match.length + match.charAt(0); 
});
```

Demo:

```
> "001100011111111111111".replace(/(0{3,9}|1{3,9})/g, function (match) { return "" + match.length + match.charAt(0); });
'0011309151'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is with `.replace()`

```
function shrink ( str ) {
    return str.replace( /(0{3,9})|(1{3,9})/g, function ( match ) {
      return match.length + match.charAt( 0 );
    } );
}
```

This would result in:

```
shrink( "10101000010111" ); //=> "10101401031"
shrink( "001100011111111111111" ); //=> "0011309151"
```

Comment: The more edits you do, the closer to @TimWolla's answer you get :)

Comment: Yea, I noticed that.  I was comparing with the expected output in my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Not javascript, but easily convertable.  Not sure if it's the most elegant, but it should be efficient.

```
public void testCompress() {
        String values = "10101000010111";
        String values2 = "0011000111111111111111";
        String compressedResult = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length();) {
            char letter = values.charAt(i);
            int numSeen = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < values.length(); j++) {
                if (values.charAt(j) == letter) {
                    numSeen++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (numSeen > 1) {
                compressedResult += numSeen;
            }
            compressedResult += letter;
            i+= numSeen;
        }
        System.err.println(compressedResult);
    }
```